# Mediawiki - Link to subpages not working properly

Tags: hyperlink, mediawiki

I am going a little bit crazy here: In some pages the internal link format **[[/link to subpage/]]** is not rendered correct.

For example (my wiki is not accessible):

Situation where it is working as expected:

> URL: mypersonalwiki.mydomain.com/index.php/examples
>   Link text: [[/subpage/]]
>   Navigation after click: mypersonalwiki.mydomain.com/index.php/examples/subpage

Situation where it is NOT working:

> URL: mypersonalwiki.mydomain.com/index.php/projects
>   Link text(the same, just copy and paste): [[/subpage/]]
>   Navigation after click: mypersonalwiki.mydomain.com/index.php//subpage/

I have tested it on blank pages and it behaves randonly: sometimes it works, sometimes not. I still have not found any common behavior pattern. Also tried disabling all extensions without any change.

Any ideas?

Edit: 
I have done some testing and maybe I found a pattern. Actually I have 3 user defined namespaces: Examples, Sandbox and Calendars.

This Wiki is enabled to be edited by anonymous users except on the "Examples" and "Calendars" ones. On these two the links are always rendered correctly. On the public namespaces (Main and Sandbox) the link is always wrong.

Thanks in advance and sorry about my english.

Comment: are `examples` and `projects` real examples? Do you have more examples of where it's working, and where it's not? Also, do you write `/subpage/`, or just `subpage`?

Comment: @leo - I changed the URLs to not expose the organization where I work. Unfortunatelly this is an internal Wiki.  About your second question, take a look at an edit I made at the original question. About your third question, I am using [[/subpage/]].

Comment: I'm asking because if they are in different namespaces, it could be a simple settings problem, but it's impossible to know from your examples.

Answer (score 1):

OK, just found it.

I forgot to enable subpages on some namespaces using the array $wgNamespacesWithSubpages[] at LocalSettings.php.

Credits to Bartosz Dziewoński from Mediawiki mailing list.